# Lubuntu 14.04 - Disable screen saver....for real this time?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, screen, screensaver

I know this has been asked multiple times. I have tried multiple things, however nothing I seem to do stick. I am trying to disable the screen saver/screen blanking on Lubuntu 14.04. I've tried the following in `rc.local`, but nothing seems to actually disable it:

```
xset -dpms xset s off xset -dpms; xset s off
setterm -blank 0 -powerdown 0 echo -ne "\033[9;0]" >> /etc/issue
```

Comment: Tried method below, no luck!

Answer (score 7):

`light-locker` lies liberally. Even with it set to disabled and with it explicitly telling me that locking was being handled by Xfce Power Manager, it still jumped in and locked the screen after resume from suspend.

Solution:

```
sudo apt-get -y remove light-locker
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem on my Lubuntu system for ages too. I did 2 things to fix it:

1. In Light Locker (`Menu > Preferences > Light Locker Settings`) make sure that '*blank
   screen*' and '*switch off display after*' are set to 'never'. Then make
   sure the 'Enable light-locker' switch is OFF.
2. In XFCE Power Manager (`Menu > Preferences > Power Manager`) select the 'On AC' menu, then click the 'monitor' tab. Make sure '*Put display to sleep when computer is inactive for*' and '*Switch off display when computer is inactive for*' are both set to 'never'. Now do the same for the 'On Battery' menu.

Make sure you hit '*Apply*' before closing each window, then reboot your computer and the problem should be fixed. It was for me anyway.

Comment: touching OnBattery settings helped me, lubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable the scren blacking use the following two commands in the **.xinitrc** file before any existing exec startlxde command:

```
xset s off &
xset -dpms &
```

If you do not have this file please create it in your home directory and paste the above content:

```
touch ~/.xinitrc
```

Make sure it is an executable script, by running

```
chmod +x ~/.xinitrc
```

Comment: the first part was done before. I am trying the "chmod +x ~/.xinitrc" to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Nope, didn't make a difference, still goes blank!

Comment: Why do we need `&` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix it by putting: "@xset s off" in my autostart file (after all other programs) and setting session idle timeout to its max value in dconf-editor (first install dconf-tools)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. Would mind adding how to find the file and how to change the settings in the dconf-editor?

Answer (score 0):

Add `@xset s off` in Start > Preferences > Default Applacations for LXSession > Autostart, where you see +Add type in the box next to it + Add Then click + Add

EDIT: Only works for a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed with the Lubuntu desktop on a computer being used mainly for netflix (Netflix now works on chrome).  In the middle of movies the screen would go blank and revert to lock screen when I pressed the spacebar.

1. After some troubleshooting, I've determined I have the known and yet unfixed bug where the PowerManager will not run.
2. I followed the directions above to deal with Lightlocker.  The settings above had no effect.  I determined I'm also having a second known bug where the settings in Lightlocker to disable screen locking are not working properly (see here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker/+bug/1287255).  What worked for me was (Menu>Preferences>Lightlocker) flip switch to disable Lightlocker altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I know what's going on here. Problem is **not** how to set the screen saver (it's really easy and the light locker settings work just like they are supposed to work) - but that sometimes it keeps mysteriously resetting to its default position (10 minutes).

How? here's the punchline. **Gnome Mplayer** resets the screensaver for some reason on pause and exit.

Here's how to fix it:

1. install VLC media player
2. open preferences->default applications
3. set default video player: VLC

and your screen saver will **stay** the way you want it to be.

Comment: Gnome Mplayer may or may not be resetting defaults, but I encountered the same issue as OP and my default video player has always been VLC. Disabling Lightlocker as mentioned in a different answer was effective on my machine.

Comment: @drkokandy: might be a different version then. I tested above behavior on Lubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
sudo apt purge xscreensaver
```