# Disable screensaver from command line in Lubuntu

Tags: command-line, 20.04, lubuntu, lock-screen

*Is there a way to disable Lunbuntu 20.04 LTS's screen saver from the command line?*

I know that it can be disabled via the system menu `Preferences -> Screen Saver` and the associated dialog box. I need to do this remotely via SSH on multiple machines, as they are consuming a lot of CPU power.

Related:

[Lubuntu - Disable screen saver....for real this time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469561)

Comment: Why not just edit (`sed`)  the `~/.xscreensaver` directly...

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, I'll look into `.xscreensaver` though I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time currently to provide more, but I'd suggest you make a copy of the file, make the change you want on a box using GUI tool, then contrast (`diff`) the changes made to that file when it's been altered to what you want/need.  It's not difficult to work out & there are docs for it (https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man2.html etc - *if unsure Ubuntu docs will lead up upstream correctly - https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xscreensaver*)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the advice.